# How to translate the alert message displayed for validations

Tags: javascript, fine-uploader

I cannot find a way to translate the error messages that are displayed in the alert box when a set a max size validation.

Comment: Please share the related code you are working with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All messages and text in Fine Uploader are overridable.  See the [`messages` option in FineUploaderBasic mode](http://docs.fineuploader.com/integrating/options/fineuploader.html#messages-option-properties), the [`messages` option in FineUploader mode](http://docs.fineuploader.com/integrating/options/fineuploaderbasic.html#messages-option-properties) to override error and other related messages.

To override any other text, see the [`text` option in FineUploaderBasic mode](http://docs.fineuploader.com/integrating/options/fineuploaderbasic.html#text-option-properties) and the [`text` option in FineUploader mode](http://docs.fineuploader.com/integrating/options/fineuploader.html#text-option-properties).

For example, if you want to customize the message that is display when a submitted item is too large, you would need to override the `sizeError` property of the `messages` option and your code may look something like this:

```
var uploader = new qq.FineUploader({
    request: {
        endpoint: 'my/endpoint'  
    },
    validation: {
        sizeLimit: 5000000    
    },
    messages: {
        sizeError: '{file} is far too big!  Your files must be restricted to {sizeLimit} or smaller.'
    }
});
```

The `{file}` text will be replaced by Fine Uploader with the file name, and the `{sizeLimit}` text will be replaced with the size limit you specified.  If you have further questions about validation or customizing messages, please refer to the documentation.

Comment: Thanks. Btw docs does not list any possible message name so I did not realize I could override a 'sizeError' message.

Comment: What if I would like to use my own custom alert box. I cannot find a way to prevent the uploader to open the browser alert allowing me to handle the exception.

Comment: @AndreaCampolonghi The docs do list possible message names.  I even linked to this portion of the docs in my answer.

Comment: @AndreaCampolonghi Contributing your own alert dialog is also covered in the documentation.  See the ["Styling Fine Uploader"](https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader/blob/master/docs/styling.md#changing-dialogs-to-something-more-user-friendly) section of the docs.

Comment: You are right. I found all the docs now that you point me directly to them. Thanks for you help. If I can suggest you something I should try to make docs more organized. The uploader works great!!

Comment: @AndreaCampolonghi  The docs are currently organized two ways: one for new users, another for reference purposes.  If you start at the [main readme page](https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader/blob/master/readme.md), you can choose either route.  There is even a step-by-step guide for new users based on one of the 4 main workflows.  Still we are constantly working to improve the documentation and make it more accessible.  There are many changes planned specifically for the readme in the near future.