# Customizing Fine Uploader delete-link's text

Tags: jquery, fine-uploader

Is it possible to customize delete link's text with Fine Uploader's own parameters. I have been able to modify large amount of other text to diffent language, but for this I didn't find solution even though it's very central text when using Fine Uploader.

I changed text manually after upload, but I don't think this is very elegant:

```
$("#upload").on("complete", function(event,id,name,response) {
    if (response["success"] == true) {
        $(this).children("div.qq-uploader").children("ul.qq-upload-list").children("li.alert-success").children(".qq-upload-delete").html("NEW DELETE TEXT");
    }
});
```

Comment: This is covered in the documentation and in a very recent Fine Uploader question on Stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16965907/how-to-translate-the-alert-message-dispalyed-for-validations.

Comment: I saw the question and I have been able to translate all the other texts I need. But even though I reread the documents which were linked to your previous answer, I couldn't find text for delete-link. Am I totally missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you found an omission in the documentation.  Good catch, and my apologies for not catching this earlier!

Fine Uploader does provide a way to customize the delete button text in FineUploader mode.  There is a `deleteButton` property on the `text` option.  It exists, but it isn't published in the documentation.  So, if you want to customize the delete button text, your client-side code might look something like this (I am using jQuery syntax since this is what you are using in your question):

```
$("#upload").fineUploader({
    request: {
        endpoint: 'my/endpoint'
    },
    text: {
        deleteButton: 'NEW DELETE TEXT'
    }
});
```

I've created [a bug in the Github project](https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader/issues/889) to remind me to update the documentation.